# Logical Children of TabControl with bound TabItems

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

I have a `TabControl` with it's `ItemsSource` bound to a `ObservableCollection<string>`. In this case, the `TabControl` has no logical children (`LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(tabctrl)` returns an empty list).

If i add a `TabItem` manually to the `TabControl.Items` collection, the `TabItem` is a logical child of the TabControl.

Why do these ways behave differently? Shouldn't the `TabControl` have a logical child in both scenarios?

Example code:

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication29.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <StackPanel>
    <TabControl Name="tabctrl"/>
    <Button Content="count children" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**code behind**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication29
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public ObservableCollection<string> TabItems
    {
      get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(TabItemsProperty); }
      set { SetValue(TabItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TabItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TabItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      TabItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
      TabItems.Add("foo");

      //scenario 1 (Visual Children count: 1, logical children count: 0)
      tabctrl.SetBinding(TabControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("TabItems") { Source = this });

      //scenario 2 (Visual Children count: 1, logical children count: 1)
      //tabctrl.Items.Add(new TabItem() { Header = "bar", Content = "bar" });

    }
    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      var visualChildrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(tabctrl);
      var logicalChildrenCount = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(tabctrl).Cast<object>().Count();

      MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Visual Children: {0}, Logical Children: {1}", visualChildrenCount, logicalChildrenCount));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you add a control to your usercontrol, or page, it is added to its LogicalTree. However, the UIElements from the control's template are not part of the LogicalTree.

IMHO, when you add TabItem directly to TabControl, you expect to be present in LogicalTree, intuitively. You have direcly added it there.

But when the items are generated from itemssource, the TabItems are generated by the control's internal logic and are not added to LogicalTree.

Maybe better example is ListBox, or DataGrid. Imagine that you have ItemsSource bound to very large collection and you need to enable virtualization. Then items (UIElements) are generated, only when needed (they are in visible area of the scrollviewver). If they were in logical tree, the logical tree would be changing while scrolling. but scrolling is more about visual than the "UI logic".

this article helps to understand the logical tree a little bit better: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21495/Understanding-the-Visual-Tree-and-Logical-Tree-in